# Restrict returned claims in Wikidata entity

Tags: api, wikidata

Is there a way to restrict the returned claims on wikidata's REST API?
For example I am using this query:

```
https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=Q17714&props=claims&format=json&languages=de|en
```

which returns all claims for the entity. But I am only interested in "P31", for example. It seems excessive to download the whole set. Any ideas?

Comment: it's not that excessive to download the entire file (in this case less than 200KB), and then filter locally.

Comment: https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetclaims&entity=Q17714&property=P31&props=&format=json ? Better learn SPARQL.

Answer (score 1):

Following Stanislavs comment:
It is possible using the REST SPARQL Endpoint at

```
https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?query=SPARQL
```

The query would be:

```
SELECT ?instanceof ?instanceofLabel WHERE {
 wd:Q17714 wdt:P31 ?instanceof.
 SERVICE wikibase:label {
  bd:serviceParam wikibase:language 'de' .
 }
}
```